# How do I clone Galdos?

Tags: endless-space

I noticed there was an achievement for cloning Galdos... at first I'd assumed it was a typo since the name of the achievement is Cake<sup>2</sup> but I just hired a Hero with this name. Do I have to be a specific race? If you can help me figure out if it's even achievable w/out spoilers that would be awesome, but considering the specificity of this question, I wouldn't be surprised if spoilers are unavoidable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloning is, of the standard races, a Horatio ability.

If you're playing as the Horatio, you can clone an existing hero rather than recruit a new one from the academy.

Answer (score 9):

1. Be Horatio
2. Hire Galdos AI hero 
   (use seed 1772120598 to start with her as one of your first three choices)
3. Clone her
   (from the academy screen)

Comment: This seed [doesn't seem](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129474/23) to be working anymore.

Comment: 4. ???
5. Profit!

Comment: user39580, can you tell us what settings you had the galaxy on? It probably still does work, but some of the settings (galaxy size/shape, etc) would need to be the same for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the seed method is that

1. You must set every single aspect of the galaxy to be the same.
2. It changes whenever new content is released (quite often)

The trick is to edit your Hero.xml file (it can't be a mod since those disable achievements)
The file is located in
Base game:
"\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Space\Public\Simulation"
Disharmony:
"\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Space\Public_xp1\Simulation"

Once there

1. Backup the file
2. Open it in an editor, such as notepad++
3. Delete all heroes except those whose ID you want to keep.

The problem is, of course, in figuring out exactly what the hero ID is.
It took some digging, reasoning, and trial and error, but I managed to find out that it is in fact "Hero48". Simply delete all other heroes
And make sure to not delete the first two lines, or anything below and including the line that says "Hero classes" (there is some code around it, but including that makes it not appear in this page